# Differentiable functions dense in Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $1\le p <\infty$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Meyers-Serrin tells us: 
$$ C^\infty(\Omega)\cap W^{k,p}(\Omega)\stackrel{dense}{\subset} W^{k,p}(\Omega)$$ 
Can one deduce the follwing?

- $$C^k(\Omega)\cap W^{k,p}(\Omega)\stackrel{dense}{\subset} W^{k,p}(\Omega)$$
- $$C^k(\Omega)\stackrel{dense}{\subset} W^{k,p}(\Omega) \qquad \text{for $\Omega$ bounded}$$

And what about $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Since $C^\infty(\Omega)\subset C^k(\Omega)$ it follows
that $C^\infty(\Omega) \cap W^{k,p}(\Omega) \subset  C^k(\Omega)\cap W^{k,p}(\Omega) \subset W^{k,p}(\Omega)$. Now the left-hand set is dense, hence the 
the set in the middle as well.

(2) This is not true as $C^k(\Omega)$ is not a subset of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.
Take for instance $\Omega=(0,1)$. Then the functions $u(x)=x^{-s}$ are in $C^k(\Omega)$ but not in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for large $s$.

(3) If we take $C^k(\bar\Omega)$ instead then $C^k(\bar\Omega)\subset W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for bounded sets $\Omega$. However, density can be proven only under some assumptions on $\Omega$.

Here, $C^k(\bar\Omega)$ denotes the space of $k$-times continuously differentiable functions on $\Omega$ with bounded and uniformly continuous derivatives up to order $k$. (I am used to this definition, it is used, e.g. in Adams' book on Sobolev spaces)

Comment: Minor nitpick: I think you want $C^k(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$. Derivatives don't play very nice on boundaries.

Comment: @Ian At which place should I put this? I don't see it.

Comment: In (3); $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ is not as sensible an object as it seems at first glance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you tell me more about (3) or cite some source (as I would be interested in the assumptions and also whether $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ or $C^k(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ to use.)

Comment: @Ian edited the answer to include the definition of $C^k(\bar\Omega)$ which I used.

Comment: @nehemoro see edit. For references: any book on Sobolev spaces and pdes will do, e.g., Evans.